# How to fix broken TextInput value updater

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get text input to print amount right to left such that...

- default: "$0.00",
- user enters 1: "$0.01",
- user enters 2: "$0.12",
- user enters 3: "$1.23",
- user enters 4: "$12.34"

... and so on. My problem is that when I do this every 3rd key press the input is adding the 3 previous presses and every now and then will press random keys. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to collect the the key press and add the keystroke combo into a state object then run it through a formatting helper method and finally set that value as the the value prop to textinput but it is not working. I've been at this on and off for weeks and would appreciate any help!

```
class EnterAmount extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            num: "",
            concatNum:""
        };
        this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    }

    printNum = (num) => {
        if(num.length === 0) {
            return '$0.00'
        } else if (num.length === 1) {
            return '$0.0' + num;
        } else if (num.length === 2) {
            return '$0.' + num
        } else {
            return '$' + num.slice(0, num.length - 2) + '.' + num.slice(num.length - 2, num.length)
        }
    }

    handleKeyPress(key) {
        console.log(key);
        if(key !== '.') { 
            this.setState(prevState=>({concatNum: prevState.concatNum + key}))
            this.setState(prevState => ({ num:  this.printNum(prevState.concatNum)}))
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>Custom Amount</Text>
                        <View>
                            <TextInput 
                                style={styles.input}
                                keyboardType={'numeric'}
                                returnKeyType={'done'}
                                onKeyPress={(e) => {this.handleKeyPress(e.nativeEvent.key)}}
                                value={this.state.num}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried the same using `onChangeText` prop of TextInput?